# How to see the (default) truststore s_client is using?

Tags: openssl

With `-CAfile` you can set the truststore of `s_client`. But how can you see the (default) truststore `s_client` is using (so if you not use `-CAfile`)?

By the way, with `curl -v` you can see the default truststore `curl` is using (if you do not use `--cacert`).

Comment: Not programming or development, but: the truststore can include (in all versions) a file settable with `-CAfile` and/or a directory settable with `-CApath` plus (in 1.0.2 up) `-verifyCAf{file,path}` and/or (in 3.0 up) URLs set with `-[verify]CAstore` ; `CA{file,path}` default to envvars `SSL_CERT_{FILE,DIR}` if set and otherwise `cert.pem` and `certs/` in a directory set at build time and shown by `openssl version -d` (except on OpenVMS it uses logname `OSSL$DATAROOT`) and `CAstore` defaults to nothing. BTW `curl -v` shows its default only for _some_ stacks.